# Drupal 6 + Ctools Page Manager + Node Over ride help

Tags: php, drupal

hey guys, having an issue and cant seem to find out whats happening,

I have basic page nodes, im using chaos tools page manager (for panels) to over ride the page for node/x, when node/x is loaded the panel I want to show kicks in and still loads the node into the new page but it doesnt seem to render CCK elements any more. ive unchecked "no extras" when putting the node content into the panel, still no luck.

I am using the rendered CCK field I need in mytheme_preprocess_page and works fine for all nodes not being overridden, loodked at the node print out of the overridden 1s and it seems to just load some node info up like below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 26
    [type] => page
    [language] => 
    [uid] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [created] => 1291494499
    [changed] => 1291495256
    [comment] => 0
    [promote] => 0
    [moderate] => 0
    [sticky] => 0
    [tnid] => 0
    [translate] => 0
    [vid] => 26
    [revision_uid] => 1
    [title] => title here
    [body] => content here
    [log] => 
    [revision_timestamp] => 1291495256
    [format] => 2
    [name] => admin
    [picture] => 
    [data] => a:0:{}
    [path] => home
    [field_page_banner] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fid] => 28
                    [list] => 1
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [alt] => 
                            [title] => 
                        )
                    [uid] => 1
                    [filename] => 28-26.png
                    [filepath] => sites/default/files/page-banners/28-26.png
                    [filemime] => image/png
                    [filesize] => 4627
                    [status] => 1
                    [timestamp] => 1291494487
                    [origname] => page-banner.png
                )
```

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 29
                [list] => 1
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [alt] => 
                        [title] => 
                    )
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => 28-26.png
                [filepath] => sites/default/files/page-banners/28-26_0.png
                [filemime] => image/png
                [filesize] => 5292
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1291495241
                [origname] => pruple-page-banner.png
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 30
                [list] => 1
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [alt] => 
                        [title] => 
                    )
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => 28-26.png
                [filepath] => sites/default/files/page-banners/28-26_1.png
                [filemime] => image/png
                [filesize] => 5209
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1291495252
                [origname] => green-page-banner.png
            )

    )

[field_homepage_block] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 
            )

    )

[field_homepage_block_order] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 
            )

    )

[field_homepage_block_image] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[last_comment_timestamp] => 1291494499
[last_comment_name] => 
[comment_count] => 0
[taxonomy] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

as you can see it never seems to fully render the node, and i need to render the CCK field used in template.php

am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution that works, in template.php im having to manually call drupal_render for the content type im using to render the cck fields, works fine now!

```
if(in_array($node->type, $banner_node_types)){

        if(!$node->content['field_page_banner']['#children']){

            $node->build_mode = 'full';
            $node = node_build_content($node);
            drupal_render($node->content);

        }

        $page_banner = $node->content['field_page_banner']['#children'];
        $vars['page_banner'] = $page_banner;

    }
```

if theres a better way please let me know! thanks :D